# How to change colors of uib tab in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, tabs

i have my business requirement that i want to change the colors of uib tab. I have dynamic tabs so whenever i add new tab i want the tabs to have its own color. I have code to generate random colors while adding tab but do not know how to change the colors of tab.

My code is:

```
<uib-tabset active="active">
    <uib-tab index="$index + 1" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" disable="tab.disabled">
    <uib-tab-heading>
        <b>{{tab.title}}</b>            
    </uib-tab-heading>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Test A</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody >
        <tr ng-repeat="content in contents ">
            <td>testing value</td>
            <td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

Adding Tab

```
$scope.addTab = function (title, view) {
  view = view || title + " Content View";
  $scope.tabs.push({ title: title, content: view, disabled: false});    
};
```

If it is not possible with uib tab then any other solution with angular js please.

Note: I do not want to use tabset

Answer (score 1):

Angular UI Bootstrap creates unordered list for the tabs. Each li element represents tab and it contains anchor element, which represents tab-headings. So, You can change the anchor element style properties such as color, background, etc., If it is dynamic then use ng-class to change the color of a tab.

For example :
Modifying color and background color of active tab:

```
.nav-tabs > li.active > a, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover{
   color : #686868;
   background-color : #ccc;
}
```

If it is dynamic then create a custom class(tab-style) and assign it to  like the following

HTML:

```
<ui-tabset class="tab-style">
   //template coding part
</ui-tabset>
```

SCSS:

```
.tab-style{
   .nav-tabs li a{
      color : //required color,
      background-color : //required color
   }
   .nav-tabs > li.active > a, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus, .nav-tabs >  li.active > a:hover{
      color : #686868;
      background-color : #ccc;
   }
}
```

If you want add separate color for each tab then add new property to $scope.tabs for each tab object say color and add that property to the tab using ng-class.

Add Tab: Example

```
$scope.addTab = function (title, view) {
   view = view || title + " Content View";
   $scope.tabs.push({ title: title, content: view, disabled: false,  color : 'red'});
};
```

In controller, you change the color property value based on requirement

HTML:

```
<uib-tabset active="active" class="custom-tab-style">
  <uib-tab index="$index + 1" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" disable="tab.disabled" ng-class="'tab' + tab.color">
    <uib-tab-heading><b>{{tab.title}}</b></uib-tab-heading>

    //template code here
</uib-tab>
```

SCSS:

```
custom-tab-style{
  .tab-red{
     a{
        color : red;
        //Here you can modify css styles for tab link
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this really easily by adding an object to your `tabs.push` statement

```
style:"{'background-color':'green'}" // replace "green" with your generated color
```

then in the usb-tabs directive add a `ng-style`

```
ng-style="{{tab.style}}"
```

You can see this in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/C2qTROJL8y0Ht6GBVCvF?p=preview%22Plunker%22)